# What caused ping.exe to return the error "application was unable to start correctly"? (0x000007b & Others)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I wrote a batch script to recursively (without using a FOR loop; as a precaution) ping all addresses from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

While running this script, it worked beautifully until ~0.0.94.100 (it's written so as to show the current address being pinged)

When I received the error 'Application was unable to start correctly, click OK to close it' it hung on the display of '0.0.94.100' until I clicked 'OK'; then resumed (and repeated the error for several other addresses after that) it should be noted that the error wasn't received by two consecutive addresses (yet; I stopped after I was forced to reboot my computer (completely froze)) (e.g. 0.0.94.100 caused an error, 0.0.94.101 did not, etc)

Every few error messages, the 0x000007b part of the error (memory address? pointer?) would change. After approx. 5-10 errors of that nature, I received an error something to the effect of 'the referenced memory could not be...' shortly after, my display driver crashed. After the driver restarted, and I continued to run the script out of curiosity, the driver continued to crash and the 'was unable to start...' continued to persistently pop up.

I've included the script's code at the bottom; is the problem arising from essentially spamming PING.EXE? Is it from trying to ping the addresses 0.X.X.X or is it another problem entirely? Any input would help. As for the purpose of the script, it's meant to be a router IP locator in case I forget the IP address (most of my router's stickers have been removed and, unfortunately, lost). I have an earlier version of this script that only went from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255 however, I now know that 4 of my routers do not use addresses within that range.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TITLE GateWay BFF
SET N1=192
SET N2=168
SET N3=0
SET N4=0
SET MFILE="!APPDATA!\..\LocalLow\ShadowCorp\GateWay BFF Results.txt"
SET FOUNDIPS=0
ECHO Results For GateWay BFF - !DATE! !TIME! >!MFILE!
ECHO Results For GateWay BFF - !DATE! !TIME!
GOTO START

:START
IF /I !N4! GTR 255 (
    SET /A N3 += 1
    SET N4=0
    IF /I !N3! GTR 255 (
        SET /A N2 += 1
        SET N3=0
        IF /I !N2! GTR 255 (
            SET /A N1 += 1
            SET N2=0
        )
    )
)
SET IPK=!N1!.!N2!.!N3!.!N4!
CLS
ECHO Pinging... ^(!IPK!^) ^(!FOUNDIPS!^)
PING -n 1 -w 100 !IPK! 1>NUL 2>NUL
IF /I !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
    SET /A FOUNDIPS += 1
    ECHO !IPK! >>!MFILE!
)
IF /I !N4! EQU 255 (
    IF /I !N3! EQU 255 (
        IF /I !N2! EQU 255 (
            IF /I !N1! EQU 255 (
                ECHO.
                ECHO DONE
                GOTO END
            )
        )
    )
)
SET /A N4 += 1
GOTO START

:END
TIMEOUT /T 3 >NUL
EXIT
```

It should also be noted that after a few crashes (display driver), some glitched graphics appeared on the screen. Though I'm certain it's not very relevant, just thought I'd include it as a precaution to what this script can do...

DO NOT RUN THE SCRIPT

It may cause temporary, serious or even irreparable damage to your computer and/or its components.

RUN AT YOUR OWN RISK

Computer Details

```
    Make: HP Pavilion 23 AIO
    OS: Windows 10 Home (Version 1709)
    OS Build: 16299.309
    Bit-depth: 64-bit
    RAM: 4GB
    Processor: Intel Core i5-4690T @ 2.5 GHz
```

I understand this error "unable to start correctly..." can be because of the MS upgrade to Windows 10, which this computer has been upgraded (from either Windows 8 or 8.1, can't recall anymore specifics at the moment). However, I have never received that error (usually caused by faulty DLLs after the upgrade, at least as far as I read) before until running the script.

Note: No internet connection was used in the testing of this script.

Link to article on 'application could not start correctly'
https://superuser.com/questions/610495/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc0000018-windows-8-x64)

Comment: Did you run it in a virtual-machine, or a physical machine? What is the version and bitness of the operating system? What security (anti-malware and firewalls) have you installed?

Comment: Physical machine; post edited to include OS Build/Bit-depth

Comment: There's nothing in the script that should be causing this issue. My initial thought is that `%APPDATA%` is full. My second thought is that you've got hardware problems.

Comment: Not sure why you would attempt to increment node 2 past 168.  192.168 is a CLASS C reserved IP address that is not route-able on the Internet.  Also it would be alot easier to check all the IP addresses if you used nested `FOR /L` commands.

Comment: Appdata is not full; I've ran /SFC and /CHKDSK are there other ways I can test for other hardware issues? @somethingdark

Comment: I'll have to do some more reading on internet protocol standards; I knew it was uncommon to go over 168, just figured I'd be thorough. Thanks for the information; I'll rewrite the script at some point using your advice. I've had some anguish using the FOR command in the past, especially when using DelayedExpansion; escaping characters is something I need to improve on (though, I wouldn't need it here; just something that deters me) @Squashman

Comment: @JoeBro, you should realize that there is no IP address that starts with a Zero in the first node.  And trying to ping every known ip address is not a good idea.  Your ISP can see that traffic and consider it to be detrimental to their network and shutdown your access to their network.

Comment: @Squashman Sorry that I didn't clarify prior; I was afraid of that very outcome; as I have a large volume of routers, I only power them on without having them connected to the internet. I have a metered data connection, so I'm frequently in airplane mode to prevent overages/etc. When running the script, I had no internet access

Comment: @JoeBro, you have a very limited knowledge of networking.  Doing what you are trying to do is not going to help you at all.  All your routers are most likely designed to use Reserved IP address on the LAN side of the router.  This means they are using 10.0.X.X, 172.16.X.X or 192.168.X.X.    If the computer you are using has an IP address of 192.168.1.100, it will not be able to communicate with the 10.0.X.X or 172.16.X.X unless you have some type of physical connection to those networks and those subnets are configured to route traffic across those networks.

Comment: @Squashman Sadly, I do have very limited knowledge when it comes to networking; I appreciate your time and effort in educating me, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If you're trying to find every device on your network, just use Nmap.